# In Android, what does it mean by Low-End (Analog) and High-End (Digital) Desk in types of dock?

Tags: android

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/docking-monitoring.html

Here, we see that there are four different type of dock. In which, Low-End (Analog) and
High-End Desk is the part of desk dock.

But **what is the meaning of it**. I searched a lot & didn't find appropriate answer.